How to invoke custom settings dynamically?
does anyone having idea how can we invoke custom settings dynamically? Please see the below example.
I need to write triggeraccount__c & triggeraccountinventory__c in separate block to check whether it's active or not. I do have 40 more custom settings to check further.
Can we make a function and just passing the name from metadata can we invoke the settings?
Boolean isTriggerInactive = false;

if(!triggeraccount__c.getInstance().Active__c){
    isTriggerInactive = true;
}
if(!triggeraccountinventory__c.getInstance().Active__c){
    isTriggerInactive = true;
}


Custom settings records can be queried using SOQL, statically or dynamically.
The problem you have with doing this for a hierarchical custom setting is that you would have to reproduce the appropriate selection of the setting based on hierarchy. The other problem you have is that your code will not benefit from caching of the custom settings.
That said, you can simulate the hierarchy handling (but not the caching, at least not without using the Platform Cache). Here's an example with static querying. You are left to convert this to dynamic SOQL and use of the SObject API:
List<SomeSettings__c> settings = [
        SELECT Id, SetupOwnerId
            FROM SomeSettings__c
            WHERE SetupOwnerId = :UserInfo.getUserId()
                OR SetupOwnerId = :UserInfo.getProfileId()
                OR SetupOwnerId = :UserInfo.getOrganizationId()
];

Map<String, SomeSettings__c> settingsByOwnerId = new Map<String, SomeSettings__c>();

for (SomeSettings__c setting : settings) {
    settingsByOwnerId.put(setting.SetupOwnerId, setting);
}

SomeSettings__c selectedRecord = settingsByOwnerId.get(UserInfo.getUserId()) ??
        settingsByOwnerId.get(UserInfo.getProfileId()) ??
        settingsByOwnerId.get(UserInfo.getOrganizationId());

At the end of this code you are left with the most appropriate settings for the contextual user (either the user-specific, profile-specific or org-wide setting, or null if there are no settings defined) in selectedRecord. You can then test for your Active__c field. Note you can access that dynamically using the SObject.get method.

You can dynamically invoke custom settings in Salesforce by creating a utility method that takes the custom setting name as a parameter and checks whether it is active. This approach will help you avoid repetitive code blocks for each custom setting.
Apex Utility Class:
public class CustomSettingUtilityClass {
        public static Boolean isCustomSettingActive(String customSettingName) {
                Boolean isActive = false;
                try {
                        SObject customSetting = (SObject) Type.forName('namespace', customSettingName).newInstance();
                        isActive = (Boolean) customSetting.get('Active__c');
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.debug('Error retrieving custom setting: ' + e.getMessage());
                }
                return isActive;
        }
}

You can now use this utility class method to check the active status of any custom setting dynamically
Boolean isTriggerInactive = false;

if (!CustomSettingUtilityClass.isCustomSettingActive('triggeraccount__c')) {
        isTriggerInactive = true;
}
if (!CustomSettingUtilityClass.isCustomSettingActive('triggeraccountinventory__c')) {
        isTriggerInactive = true;
}

// Add more custom settings checks as needed

For more information:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_type.htm#apex_System_Type_forName_2
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm

Update:
I have tried the below code in my org.
Utility Class:
public class CustomSettingUtilityClass {
    public static Boolean isCustomSettingActive(String customSettingName) {
        Boolean isActive = false;
        try {
            Type t = Type.forName(customSettingName);
            SObject customSetting = (SObject) t.newInstance();
            List<SObject> customSettingsRecords = Database.query('SELECT Name, t561258__Active__c FROM ' + customSettingName + ' LIMIT 1');
            
            if (customSettingsRecords.size() > 0) {                
                // Loop through the records
                for (SObject record : customSettingsRecords) {
                    System.debug('Record Name: ' + record.get('Name'));
                    System.debug('Field Value: ' + record.get('t561258__Active__c'));
                    isActive = (Boolean) record.get('t561258__Active__c');
                }
            }
            
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('Error retrieving custom setting: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
        return isActive;
    }
}

For testing, I have run the below code into the anonymous window of my developer console.
Boolean val = CustomSettingUtilityClass.isCustomSettingActive('t561258__UserData__c');

if (!val) {
    system.debug('Called the custom setting and get the value: '+ val);
} else {
    system.debug('Called the custom setting and get the value: '+ val);
}

In the above code, t561258__UserData__c is the custom setting.

Output:


Your code doesn't load the custom settings record, but instead creates a new in-memory record, so this won't work.

You unnecessarily call newInstance still, and fail to consider hierarchy because you only query one record. You could randomly get org-wide, profile or user specific value.
